# автоинкремент пишет только нечетные значения

Tags: mysql

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: в таблице БД есть поле id, оно понятное дело автоинкремент. Но, почему то при добавлении записи поле заполняется тоьлко нечетными данными(1,3,5,7,9 и т.д.). Проблема в целом для всех таблиц БД. Может кто знает в чем проблема может бытЬ?

Comment: звучит так, как-будто у вас репликация настроена. Смотрите auto_increment_increment в mysql.cnf

Comment: А может действительно настроена репликация master-master?

Comment: репликация, настроена, но данные идентичные в базах. Дело. действительно, было в конфигах.

Comment: @Дмитрий вы знаете зачем это было сделано? Уже успели перезапустить mysql? :)

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, нет не знаю. просветите?

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, почитал))) ну чтож тоже не зря полез туда, поправил конфиг, чтобы, в одной были четные в другой нечетные. только не получается воспроизвести ситуацию чтобы меня спроксировало на вторую базу где пойдут четные номера...

Comment: Без полного понимания вашей конфигурации преждевременно что-то пытаться объяснить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте комманду

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

**Обновление:**

---

указанный выше случай распространяется только для выбранной таблицы. Если вы хотите чтобы данное условие распространялось на все таблицы в бд то попробуйте в файле `my.ini` сделать поправку

```
auto-increment-increment = 1
auto-increment-offset = 1
```

Comment: действительно в конфигах было: auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 1.